# show stopper error "Undefined variable: javascript" in cakephp app

Tags: cakephp

This one is a truly weird bug.
This app works on my local machine and in production, just fine, but on my staging server it bjorks ... with the error given above.

The offending line of code is in /app/views/layout/default.ctp

```
  <?php echo $javascript->link('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js') ?>
```

and yes I have this in /app/controllers/app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller{
    public $helpers = array('Javascript', 'Form', 'Html', 'Page');
    ...
}
```

I've been trying to figure out the problem for hours ...
Running PHP 5.2.14 on the staging server, and 5.2.5 on my local machine. 
Using CakePHP 1.2.6

Any ideas on how to even start tackling this would be much appreciated

Full Error below

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: javascript [APP/views/layouts/default.ctp, line 6]
Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object in /x/x/x/x/app/views/layouts/default.ctp on line 6
```

Comment: probably different version of CakePHP (1.3 I guess) is on the server.

Comment: Check mod_rewrite is installed and working correctly on the server. Check your .htaccess file.

Comment: @Sergei ... how could that be? ... The app is self contained and is stored along with the cake folder in subversion.

Comment: @Leo. Done and Done. Both seem to be working just fine

Answer (score 0):

Does the trailing php marker ".`.. 'Html', 'Page');?>`" in the controller code actually appear in your real app_controller? "

Please tell me this isn't the path to your AppController: "`/app/controllers/app_controller.ctp`"

`app_controller.php` (note the filetype) should live in the app folder.

Comment: Good catch, but those are mistakes I made formatting the code to display on here. The file is named app_controller.php and the trailer php marker isn't there in the code.